# Blockchair API request transaction limit

Tags: python, pandas, request, transactions, restful-url

I'm using [blockchair API](https://blockchair.com/api/docs#link_300) to get a transaction history from a wallet, but when I run the code it only returns 100 records even though it has more than it. You can try running this.

```py
url = ('https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin/dashboards/address/19iqYbeATe4RxghQZJnYVFU4mjUUu76EA6?transaction_details=true?limit=500')

# json
response = requests.get(url)  # Make a GET request to the URL
data = response.json()  # Parse `response.text` into JSON
len(data['data']['19iqYbeATe4RxghQZJnYVFU4mjUUu76EA6']['transactions'])
```

I'm trying to understand why it doesn't return the total amount of records, for example if you run:

```py
data['data']
```

you'll get that the number of transactions is:

```py
'transaction_count': 44157,
```

The documentation says that with `?limit={:limit}` you can set the limit is transaction which is `100` by default, I set it to `500` but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think that API has a max limit is 100 transactions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).